# "SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM table" query works only after "SELECT * FROM table" has been called

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

The below function is in a javascript file. The intent is to return the maximum value in the rowid column of a sqlite database. Currently, it works only after a "Select * from table query" has been run. Why is this?

```
function lastRecord(){  
db.transaction(function (tx) {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT MAX(rowid) as mr FROM Surveys', [], function(tx, results){
  var maxRowid = results.rows.item(0).mr;
  alert(maxRowid);
});
});
}
```

I would appreciate clarification regarding what needs to be loaded to get SELECT MAX(rowid) to show the correct MAX rowid value every time the function is called. What is the standard format (structure) for implementing the MAX function? THANKS.

Comment: You're exposing your database to the world via a scripting language. That screams 'bad idea' to me.

Comment: @McAden it's a SQLite database kept in the browser I think; it's like a gigantic cookie :)

Comment: This app will be on small portable devices not connected to the internet.

Comment: What's the error/return?

Comment: @user2676598 "Security through obscurity, is not security". Always remember that just because it's a hidden Javascript file on a mobile app, doesn't mean your users can't extract it.

Comment: Is it because MAX() is an aggregate function?

Comment: Yes Alex, I believe this to be the case.

Comment: @user2676598 This query should work. You have to show more code, especially the opening of the database and the first query.

Comment: The security here could be fine ... Just because its a database doesnt need to be secure. If its a per user application database then there are no security concerns here.

Comment: @gbtimmon preventing users from reverse engineering applications is a form of security too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The problem was HTML related: not a SQL issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using an order by and a limit? Something like

```sql
Select rowid as mr from surveys order by rowid desc limit 1
```

might work better for you.

Comment: The current language works spectacular AFTER I've run a, "Select * from table query". I can't seem to figure out precisely what the resource is that's being loaded at this point, or exactly how to replicate it.

Comment: Okay- the order by and limit solution works in this instance. Kudos to user2628209...however, I'd still like to know where I am missing the boat w/the aggregate function. Would I insult people if I added the rest of the javescript file to the code above? Thanks.

Comment: This format, "SELECT rowid AS mr FROM Surveys WHERE rowid = (select MAX(rowid) FROM Surveys" performs identical as the, "SELECT MAX(rowid) as mr FROM Surveys" in that it only works after a  "Select * from table query" has run.

Comment: seeing more of the file might give an insight into whats going wrong, I don't see why it would only work after the select * query. Perhaps it's something else in the code you left out?

Comment: Similar to my most recent comment,  "SELECT MAX(1,3,5,7,11,13) as mr" performs identical as "SELECT MAX(rowid) as mr FROM Surveys" in that it only works after a "Select * from table query" has run. 
However, "SELECT RANDOM() as mr" does NOT return a rn. Other tested aggregate functions such as MIN do work in the flawed manner previously described.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the maximum row ID from those in a range, you can execute the following:

```
SELECT MAX(rid) as mr FROM (
  SELECT rowid as rid FROM surveys ORDER BY rowid LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 0
)
```

## How it Works

- The inner (parenthesised) `SELECT` gets the row IDs for the specific range. (The `OFFSET` of a limit dictates which row to start from, where the first row in a table is row 0. Think of it as how many rows to skip, from the start.)
- The outer `SELECT`, `SELECT MAX(rid)`, gets the maximum value from that range.